# How to display multiple .tif in C#?

Tags: c#, image-processing, tiff

Is there any simple way to open and display multipage .tif files? I want to write a simple winForm application to open multiple page .tif file and scrolling around these pages? I want to add next and previous buttons to my project to scroll around them. Any suggestions or examples?

Comment: Actually, what you want is to give you the complete program ?

Comment: Of course no Jaroslaw,
Thanks Karl I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

Try the free [DotImage Photo SDK](http://www.atalasoft.com/free-dotnet-image-sdk) by Atalasoft. Though it is not open source, it is free and a very good choice for viewing images.

Meanwhile I will have a look if [AForge.Net](http://www.aforgenet.com/) and [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) can open Multipage TIFF images and let you know. These frameworks are open source and include very powerful SDKs for image processing.

Answer (score 0):

I know an SDK named leadtools that has the ability to load and display multipage TIF files using .NET. For a sample code, see the following link:
http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/to/leadtools.topics~leadtools.topics.loadingsavingtutorials.html

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [faq#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and **target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future**. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.